# American English: "walk with" meaning "bring"

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, prepositions, american-english

Is it idiomatic or slang American English to say "I am walking with a small suitcase" to mean "I am bringing a small suitcase"?  Other examples I've heard: "I didn't walk with enough supplies for this trip".  Meaning the person didn't bring enough supplies.

I can't find any references on Google for usage of such an expression in the English language.

**If someone can give me a precise answer backed up by English grammar or other documentation it would be great.**

Comment: I've heard it once or twice (in 68 years) but it's not especially common in the US, and would be confusing to many.

Comment: It should be noted that various rural cultures in the US tend to exchange the roles of "bring", "take", "carry", et al.  But I would guess that those who do this comprise less than 5% of the population.

Comment: What led you to think this is a possible phrase to begin with? Do you have  link to that original?

Comment: I heard it and the person (not a native speaker) claims it is normal usage in American English, which I have never heard in my life.  I'm not a native speaker nor leave in the U.S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Walk with* for "bring (along)" or "supply oneself with" is not an English idiom.

Answer (score 1):

The expression ***[walk with something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/walk+with)*** means:

> to walk with the aid of something, such as a cane, crutches, etc.
>
> - You can recognize her easily. She walks with a cane. Dan walks with the help of a crutch.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verb)

- But walking with a bag does mean walking carrying a bag.

Comment: Added another example of usage I have heard. I would like to know if this is legitimate usage of english.